# Web-based page session

Tags: javascript, scala, session, web, web-applications

I'd like to create a web app where the user is able to create a session, with the session being accessible even after leaving the page/browser.

An example would be http://lichess.org where the user goes to 'Create a game' and a page is created. That page then remains accessible even after the session is finished; see: http://en.lichess.org/i8pV0vEv

Essentially what I'd like to know is, what would be needed in order to create a similar effect. I've programmed tonnes over the years, just web environments are new to me! Scala seems like a contender, but in all honesty I have no clue. Perhaps javascript?

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store user session data permanently irrespective of whether user is on the website or not you may use browser storage facility of HTML 5.
where you can store data on user's browser in form of key value pair and the data will be there permanently(based on type of browser storage you are using) and you can easily manipulate data using javascript.
There are mainly two types of browser storage.

- **Local Storage**: will be there permanently and can be accessed anytime you want.
- **Session Storage**: will be there till the page is open and cleared when user close the browser window.

For your requirement my recommendation is to go for **Local Storage**

Advantages of Using Local Storage

- Can be manipulated easily using JavaScript.
- Will be permanent.
- No server-side scripting hence, fast to load and manage.

Disadvantages of using local storage

- won't work in browser not supporting HTML5(supported in IE 8,chrome 4,Mozilla 3.5,safari 4,opera 11.5 and above)
- User will be able to manipulate/delete the value(The browser storage value can be manipulated using resource option of Browser developer tool)
- Wont be permanent if user is visiting in In-cognito/in-private mode.(but will be stored during the session.)
- Data limit of at least 5MB
- Data will be deleted when user clears browser history.

for further reference checkout w3schoold
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: I really appreciate the time taken to write your comment. I'll take a look into local storage, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Web programming is generally session-less and you need a [cookie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) to simulate a session. You save this in your client's browser and in a database to be able to tie them together. Or you can use the browser-session which in the end is also a cookie, but does not scale very well as it's saved in the internal mechanisms of the web-server.

There's nothing Scala specific here, but if you would like to give Scala a try, have a look at [Play framework](https://www.playframework.com/). It's pretty beginner friendly and already has built in support for everything you would need like [Sessions](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaSessionFlash), [Cookies](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Cookie) and [Database](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaDatabase) access.